# Reading large xml file makes the server stop working - out of memory

Tags: c#, xml

I have a piece of code which works well for normal files. But for really big files, it makes the server stop working.

Here it is:

```
XmlReader reader = null;
try
{
    reader = XmlReader.Create(file_name + ".xml");
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(reader);
    XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = GetNamespaceManager(reader);
    XElement root = xml.Root;

    //XAttribute supplier = root.XPathSelectElement("//sh:Receive/sh:Id", namespaceManager).Attribute("Authority");

    //string version = root.XPathSelectElement("//sh:DocumentId/sh:Version", namespaceManager).Value;

    var nodes = root.XPathSelectElements("//eanucc:msg/eanucc:transact", namespaceManager);

    return nodes;                
}
catch
{ }
```

I think this is the part which causes the memory problem which happens on the server. How can I fix this?

Comment: How many `transact` elements are there? (This may not even be feasible...)

Comment: Can you give us an idea about the size of the files that cause the error? Is it a single file or is it multiple large files?

Comment: @Jras A single file. It has about 8.000 nodes.

Comment: @petko_stankoski: But how big are those nodes? How much of the file consists of `transact` elements, and how much is other elements? How big is the file itself?

Comment: @JonSkeet 99% of the file are transact nodes. The other 1% is the header node. I should also add that the transact nodes are into msg nodes.

Comment: Okay, so basically you're trying to read more data than you can fit into memory. That's not going to work. You're going to have to use an iterator block, I suspect.

Comment: @JonSkeet How do you mean iterator block? So there is a way after all?

Comment: @petko_stankoski: See my answer. But you should read up on iterator blocks as well, to understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like there's simply too much data to read in one go. You'll have to iterate over the elements one at a time, using `XmlReader` as a cursor, and converting one element to `XElement` at a time.

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> ReadTransactions()
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(file_name + ".xml"))
    {
        while (reader.ReadToFollowing("transact", eanuccNamespaceUri))
        {
            using (var subtree = reader.ReadSubtree())
            {
                yield return XElement.Load(subtree);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this assumes there are never "transact" elements at any other level. If there are, you'll need to be more careful with your `XmlReader` than just calling `ReadToFollowing`. Also note that you'll need to find the actual namespace URI of the `eanucc` alias.

Don't forget that if you try to read *all* of this information in one go (e.g. by calling `ToList()`) then you'll still run out of memory. You need to *stream* the information. (It's not clear what you're trying to do with the elements, but you need to think about it carefully.)

Comment: I'm trying to count them, to find out how many transact elements are in the file. How would I call ReadTransactions()?

Comment: @petko_stankoski: If you're *just* trying to count them, you don't need to load them at all. I wish you'd said that before. That said, you could always use `int count = ReadTransactions.Count();`

Comment: Tnx, you really helped. But reader.ReadSubtree() returns empty.

Comment: @petko_stankoski: What do you mean by "returns empty"? What are you trying to do with it? It doesn't help that you haven't given an example of your XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the reader in a using(){} clause so it gets disposed of after use.

```
try
{
    using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(file_name + ".xml"))
    {
      XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(reader);
      XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = GetNamespaceManager(reader);
      XElement root = xml.Root;

      var nodes = root.XPathSelectElements("//eanucc:msg/eanucc:transact", namespaceManager);

      return nodes;
    }                
}
catch
{ }
```

Comment: put more details in your answer. avoid one line/short answers. dont ask questions in your answer, use comments for that purpose.